# Cypress Test Chaining Assertions - Error When Using Multiple .should() Commands

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm currently working on writing Cypress tests for a React application, and I've come across an issue when chaining multiple assertions using the .should() command. When I try to chain the assertions, I encounter an error, but the tests work fine when the assertions are separate. Here's an example of my code and the issue I'm facing:
Test Case 1 (Working):

```
it('validate the form', () => {
  cy.visit('/about');

  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').should('have.text', 'Send Message');
  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').click();
  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').should('have.text', 'Sending...');
  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').should('have.text', 'Send Message');
});
```

Test Case 2 (Not Working):

```
it('validate the form', () => {
  cy.visit('/about');

  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').should('have.text', 'Send Message');
  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').click();
  cy.get('[data-cy="contact-btn"]').should('have.text', 'Sending...').should('have.text', 'Send Message');
});
```

In Test Case 1, where I separate the assertions, the test passes without any issues. However, in Test Case 2, when I try to chain the assertions together, my test fails

I'm not sure why this error occurs when I chain the assertions, and I would like to understand the reason behind it. Can someone explain why Cypress behaves differently in these two scenarios and how I can successfully chain multiple assertions on the same element?

Comment: Because [_"some chainers change the subject"_](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Yields).

Answer (score 4):

From the logic of the app, the text `Sending...` and `Send Message` would appear on the element at ***sequentially***.

By chaining the two different `.should('have.text', ...)`, you are implying that the the two texts ***appear on the element at the same time*** - which is clearly impossible.

Remember that `.should()` assertions invoke a retry of the preceding `cy.get()` until the assertion is satisfied. But ***all*** the assertions are retried, so the whole chain must be valid within the same timeout period.

If you want to assert a sequence of page events, then Test Case 1 is your only option, because the second `.should()` assertion will not be started until the first one succeeds.

---

By the way, it's more conventional to use `cy.get().should(...).and(...)`, where `.and()` is a synonym for `.should()`.

Using these semantics, it becomes clear that the two conditions are simultaneous.

Comment: .should() assertions invoke a retry of the preceding cy.get() until the assertion is satisfied .... 
this was the answer i was looking for!